# How to match a pattern with multi-line and displays them?

Tags: c, regex, grep

I have a head file (.h) which contains the definition of structures in C.

Some are defined like this:

```
typedef struct {
 ...
 ...
 ...
} structure1
```

Some are defined like this:

```
typedef struct structure2 {
 ...
 ...
 ...
} structure2
```

and some commanded out structure definition:
Some are defined like this:

```
//typedef struct {
// ...
// ...
// ...
//} structure1
```

How can I use egrep or more unix command to find all the structures in the head file and print all the names of structures?

Thanx.

Comment: sniff sniff... homework?

Comment: not a homework, a part of my personal work which helps detect the size changes of all structures defined in a .h file.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to do this in a single line command, but it looks like more are needed to me. So want to ask for ideas to do this simply.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy with `perl`:

```
perl -e 'local $/; $_ = <>; print $1."------\n" while (/(typedef struct {.*?}.*?\n)/msg);'
```

Example:

```
$ cat /tmp/1.txt 
typedef struct {
 ...
 ...
 ...
} structure1

hello

typedef struct {
 ...
 ...
 ...
} structure2

bye

$ cat /tmp/1.txt | perl -e 'local $/; $_ = <>; print $1."------\n" while (/(typedef struct {.*?}.*?\n)/msg);'
typedef struct {
 ...
 ...
 ...
} structure1
------
typedef struct {
 ...
 ...
 ...
} structure2
------
```

Founded blocks separated  with `---------`.

When you want to get only structures' names you must group another part of the regular expression (you group the part you need using `()`):

```
$ cat /tmp/1.txt | perl -e 'local $/; $_ = <>; print $1."\n" while (/typedef struct {.*?}\s*(.*?)\n/msg);'
structure1
structure2
```

As you can see, I modified the regular expression a little bit:

```
/typedef struct {.*?}\s*(.*?)\n/
```

The part of the string that goes after `}` will be captured into the group `$1`.

Comment: Thanks lgor. modify to cat /tmp/1.txt | perl -e 'local $/; $_ = <>; print $1."------\n" while (/(^typedef struct [ a-zA-Z_]*{.*?}.*?\n)/msg);' works for me. Then what command can help to extract only the name of the structure?

Comment: added explanation for the struct's name